# Использование generics в Delphi: неизвестный тип данных TList

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-xe2

Пробую использовать generics:

```
var List: TList<Integer>;
```

но RAD Studio мне подчеркивает неизвестный тип данных `TList`, хотя в коде `var List: TList;` - никаких проблем нет. В чем тут может быть проблема? Юнит `Classes`, естественно, подключен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ найден: нужно подключить еще и юнит System.Generics.Collections